# Loading Angular2 Components from separate IIS Applications

Tags: visual-studio, angular, asp.net-core-mvc

We are moving to a micro services architecture on the back end, and would like if possible to split the front end into separate visual studio solutions that could be deployed as individual IIS applications. this is so that we can allow developers to work on each solution in isolation.

the main site application would contain the navigation when clicking a nav item the MVC view from a sub application would be loaded into a content area.

Each of the sub applications would contain an angular2 module app, that would be loaded into the content area dynamically.

Is this possible, has anyone implemented anything like this, from the way web pack is packaging up the app, it appears that angular2 has been designed to run as a monolithic single page application and all components must be available on first load.

The thing we are struggling with most is loading an angular module dynamically from a sub IIS application.

Comment: did you get a solution? am also looking for this.